# Liferay HTTP Status 414 - Request-URI Too Long after changing page permissions

Tags: liferay

I was changing page permissions in Liferay and suddenly got an `HTTP Status 414 - Request-URI Too Long` error. Liferay Portal is deployed on `Glassfish`. The user that was logged in (admin) was able to normally navigate the portal, but guest could only see the error above. Once I logged out of my account, I could no longer enter the portal page.

Following is the URL I get when trying to enter localhost:8080. Seems like Liferay mistakenly adds 25's to this Link:

http://localhost:8080/c/portal/login?redirect=%2Fweb%2Fguest%2Fhome%3Fp_p_state%3Dmaximized%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26saveLastPath%3Dfalse%26_58_struts_action%3D%252Flogin%252Flogin%26p_p_id%3D58%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26_58_redirect%3D%252Fweb%252Fguest%252Fhome%253Fp_p_state%253Dmaximized%2526p_p_mode%253Dview%2526saveLastPath%253Dfalse%2526_58_struts_action%253D%25252Flogin%25252Flogin%2526p_p_id%253D58%2526p_p_lifecycle%253D0%2526_58_redirect%253D%25252Fweb%25252Fguest%25252Fhome%25253Fp_p_state%25253Dmaximized%252526p_p_mode%25253Dview%252526saveLastPath%25253Dfalse%252526_58_struts_action%25253D%2525252Flogin%2525252Flogin%252526p_p_id%25253D58%252526p_p_lifecycle%25253D0%252526_58_redirect%25253D%2525252Fweb%2525252Fguest%2525252Fhome%2525253Fp_p_state%2525253Dmaximized%25252526p_p_mode%2525253Dview%25252526saveLastPath%2525253Dfalse%25252526_58_struts_action%2525253D%252525252Flogin%252525252Flogin%25252526p_p_id%2525253D58%25252526p_p_lifecycle%2525253D0%25252526_58_redirect%2525253D%252525252Fweb%252525252Fguest%252525252Fhome%252525253Fp_p_state%252525253Dmaximized%2525252526p_p_mode%252525253Dview%2525252526saveLastPath%252525253Dfalse%2525252526_58_struts_action%252525253D%25252525252Flogin%25252525252Flogin%2525252526p_p_id%252525253D58%2525252526p_p_lifecycle%252525253D0%2525252526_58_redirect%252525253D%25252525252Fweb%25252525252Fguest%25252525252Fhome%25252525253Fp_p_state%25252525253Dmaximized%252525252526p_p_mode%25252525253Dview%252525252526saveLastPath%25252525253Dfalse%252525252526_58_struts_action%25252525253D%2525252525252Flogin%2525252525252Flogin%252525252526p_p_id%25252525253D58%252525252526p_p_lifecycle%25252525253D0%252525252526_58_redirect%25252525253D%2525252525252Fweb%2525252525252Fguest%2525252525252Fhome%2525252525253Fp_p_state%2525252525253Dmaximized%25252525252526p_p_mode%2525252525253Dview%25252525252526saveLastPath%2525252525253Dfalse%25252525252526_58_struts_action%2525252525253D%252525252525252Flogin%252525252525252Flogin%25252525252526p_p_id%2525252525253D58%25252525252526p_p_lifecycle%2525252525253D0%25252525252526_58_redirect%2525252525253D%252525252525252Fweb%252525252525252Fguest%252525252525252Fhome%252525252525253Fp_p_state%252525252525253Dmaximized%2525252525252526p_p_mode%252525252525253Dview%2525252525252526saveLastPath%252525252525253Dfalse%2525252525252526_58_struts_action%252525252525253D%25252525252525252Flogin%25252525252525252Flogin%2525252525252526p_p_id%252525252525253D58%2525252525252526p_p_lifecycle%252525252525253D0%2525252525252526_58_redirect%252525252525253D%25252525252525252Fweb%25252525252525252Fguest%25252525252525252Fhome%25252525252525253Fp_p_state%25252525252525253Dmaximized%252525252525252526p_p_mode%25252525252525253Dview%252525252525252526saveLastPath%25252525252525253Dfalse%252525252525252526_58_struts_action%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252Flogin%2525252525252525252Flogin%252525252525252526p_p_id%25252525252525253D58%252525252525252526p_p_lifecycle%25252525252525253D0%252525252525252526_58_redirect%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252Fweb%2525252525252525252Fguest%2525252525252525252Fhome%2525252525252525253Fp_p_state%2525252525252525253Dmaximized%25252525252525252526p_p_mode%2525252525252525253Dview%25252525252525252526saveLastPath%2525252525252525253Dfalse%25252525252525252526_58_struts_action%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252Flogin%252525252525252525252Flogin%25252525252525252526p_p_id%2525252525252525253D58%25252525252525252526p_p_lifecycle%2525252525252525253D0%25252525252525252526_58_redirect%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252Fweb%252525252525252525252Fguest%252525252525252525252Fhome%252525252525252525253Fp_p_state%252525252525252525253Dmaximized%2525252525252525252526p_p_mode%252525252525252525253Dview%2525252525252525252526saveLastPath%252525252525252525253Dfalse%2525252525252525252526_58_struts_action%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252Flogin%25252525252525252525252Flogin%2525252525252525252526p_p_id%252525252525252525253D58%2525252525252525252526p_p_lifecycle%252525252525252525253D0%2525252525252525252526_58_redirect%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252F&p_l_id=10183

Comment: Try this : use browser anonymous navigation and try again..

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. But if it had worked, what would be the logic behind it?

Comment: Maybe there was a session cookie for a different liferay version. I noticed that this situation lead to break auto login and generate bad redirect like the long url..

Answer (score 0):

The length of request uri is configurable in the server. I encountered the same problem when I use Liferay on tomcat. And I solved it by changing tomcat/conf/server.xml, added maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" to this element：

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Then it becomes：

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

And I believe you can also find such configuration file in Glassfish.

[Reference](https://serverfault.com/questions/56691/whats-the-maximum-url-length-in-tomcat)